# /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py:40: UserWarning: [Errno 30] Read-only file system. joblib will operate in serial mode

Tags: python, python-module

Anyone knows what this error is and how to fix it?

I've already tried to 

**chmod -R 777 /usr/local/python2.6/dist-packages/joblib** but with no luck.

Comment: Your filesystem is mounted read-only. Permissions aren't going to fix that.

Comment: My filesystem is mounted as read and write. Both /usr/local and the script I have on /home/username/ are in the same partition mounted under read/write priveleges

Comment: I have an R script that runs in parallel currently on the server. Do you think that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/dev/shm was mounted as readonly on ubuntu 10.04

```
$ mount | grep shm
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (ro)
```

This fixed the problem:

```
sudo mount -v -o remount,rw /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions for the directory the process wants to write to. Find out what directory `joblib` wants to put things in and change its permissions or use a different directory with the needed permissions for this. In order to be able to give the permissions and to allow Python to write to the filesystem, it must be mounted in a way that allows writing.

Comment: He's getting EROFS (read-only filesystem). If it were just a permission problem, he'd be getting EACCESS (permission denied). The problem is that his filesystem is mounted read-only.

Comment: Ok. The process of given permissions would then include mounting the file system accordingly. It is a problem on the OS level and not Python-specific.